# Debugging a ClickOnce application and passing startup command parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

In a traditional WinForms app you can pass command line arguments via the debug section of the projects settings.  This is great when you want to test various startup parameters from within Visual Studio as you run the app.

For a ClickOnce application my understanding is that the URL parameters are pulled from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.  However the command line arguments section is ignored.  So my question is, how can I pass a URL query which is retrieved from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments during the application startup process. At the moment I have an application which quits straight away if the passed URL is empty.  So as you can imagine, it makes development/testing a tad difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that there really is a way to do what you want.
If you want to do something like this try using:

```
#if DEBUG

//Code goes here

#endif
```

This code will only be run, if the current build is set to "Debug".
If you want you can then use the normal Command-Line-Arguments via the projects settings and access them either via:

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

or if you are in the main method (e.g. App.Xaml.cs in Application_Startup) you can do this:

```
e.Args //or something similar
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you lightlike!  Love the idea of using the #if DEBUG approach, that will do the trick! :o)